# UIViewControllers inheritance or protocols

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, uiviewcontroller, protocols

I am making an app where many `View Controllers` will have the same set of `UIViews`. I write UI in code and would like to avoid rewriting the same code over and over again. Each ViewController will have the same main button and back button, and then some of them will have another set of labels repeated as well. I was wondering which approach should be better for me, using Inheritance of `UIViewControllers` like that:

```
VC1: UIViewController with main button and back button
VC2: VC1 with added labels
VC3: VC1 with added other labels
```

Or should I use protocols for adding labels like that:

```
protocol HasLabels {
    var label1: UILabel { get set }
    var label2: UILabel { get set }

    func setupLabels()
}


extension HasLabels where Self: VC1 {
    func setupLabels() {
        self.view.addSubview(label1)
        self.view.addSubview(label2)
        // setting up constraints
    }
}
```

Or should I just set up views in each UIViewController separately and not overcomplicate that?

Comment: Just make UIView class, and put the programmatically UI code there. when you are implementing the UIView from the view controller, just add the class in via iboutlet. for me that's the easiest way

Comment: Before I use inheritance, I think about the L in SOLID. An instance of the parent class should be substitutable with an instance of its subclasses, without causing problems. If there really is a relationship between the classes that makes inheritance worth while then this rule holds true. Otherwise, I'd go for protocol extensions, or composition (a custom view class perhaps). A rule of thumb one of my colleagues uses, is to ask himself if it makes sense that `Class B is a Class A` (where A is the superclass). If that sentence makes no sense, he avoids inheritance.

Comment: Neither inheritance nor protocols are the right tool for the job here. I suggest combining your UIViews if possible, or using view controller containment. View controller containment means you’re combining multiple view controllers in a parent/child type relationship.